# Cocoa - How to bring particular window to come in foreground from StatusMenu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsstatusitem

I am working on an Mac Application. I have set `Application is agent (UIElement) = YES` in plist, and App have a Window *(lets say Popup Window)* that acts as custom PopOver for StatusMenu. One more window is there *(lets say Window B)* that should opened on selecting a Link from StatusMenu that i have made, but Problems that I am facing are as follow:

- On Application launch, When I ***opens status Menu It also showing Window B***, that actually should not be Shown. Window B is allocated and initialised in Application Delegate.
- Another Issue is When Window B is made Visible by Selecting it from StatusMenu. It appears well, Now i switch to another application so Its window is sent to background that is fine, ***but Whenever I click on Status Menu, It  automatically comes in Front.*** Ideally It should only open Popup window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Window B is opening because you might be forgot to un-check "Visible At Launch" window property in attribute inspector of interface builder

[image]

- 2nd issue you can resolve by activateIgnoringOtherApps set to YES before calling your window

  ```
  [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

  [windowB showWindow:nil];
  ```